# Rewrite URL characters in Joomla with htaccess or router.php

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, url-rewriting, router

In order to avoid a URL problem in Joomla (components conflict) I must place a dash after a slash :D Example URL "...blog/-article-name" What I need now is to rewrite "/-" to "/" I've spend quite some time to find how to do it with a router.php but with no success. Now I ask for help. Can someone tell me how to do it with htaccess or router.php?
Thanks in advance.

This is where I tried to insert the recommended rule in my htaccess:

```
#####################################################
#  READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
#
#####################################################

##  Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks

#
#  mod_rewrite in use
/********** TRYED HERE ********/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
/********** TRYED HERE ********/
RewriteEngine On
/********** TRYED HERE ********/

########## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits
## If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
## This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
## Deny access to extension xml files (uncomment out to activate)
#<Files ~ "\.xml$">
#Order allow,deny
#Deny from all
#Satisfy all
#</Files>

## End of deny access to extension xml files
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode crap to send via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Send all blocked request to homepage with 403 Forbidden error!
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]
#
########## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits

#  Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
#  is not directly related to physical file paths.
#  Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root)

RewriteBase /
/********** TRYED HERE ********/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.mysite.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://mysite.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
/********** TRYED HERE ********/

#Check to see if browser can accept gzip files.
ReWriteCond %{HTTP:accept-encoding} (gzip.*)
#make sure there’s no trailing .gz on the url
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^.+gz$
#check to see if a .gz version of the file exists.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}gz -f
#All conditions met so add .gz to URL filename (invisibly)
RewriteRule ^(.+) $1gz [L]
AddType “text/css;charset=UTF-8? .cssgz
AddEncoding gzip .cssgz
AddType “text/javascript;charset=UTF-8? .jsgz
AddEncoding gzip .jsgz

# Disable calls to user registration or password or username reset ("register", "remind", "reset")
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/user/(remind|reset|register)(\.html)? [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} option=com_user&view=(remind|reset|register)

# Send all blocked request to homepage with 403 Forbidden error!
RewriteRule index\.php$ http://new.marioiliev.com/ [R=301,L]

########## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
#
########## End - Joomla! core SEF Section

# Deny access to php, xml and ini files 
# within components and plugins directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.php|\.ini|\.xml [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/components\/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/includes\/|^\/administrator\/includes\/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/language\/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/libraries\/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/modules\/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/plugins\/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/templates\/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/xmlrpc\/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [R=404,L]

# Prevent most common SQL-Injections
RewriteCond %{query_string} concat.*\( [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} union.*select.*\( [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} union.*all.*select [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]

# Block most common hacking tools
SetEnvIf user-agent "Indy Library" stayout=1
SetEnvIf user-agent "libwww-perl" stayout=1
SetEnvIf user-agent "Wget" stayout=1
deny from env=stayout
```

Comment: Do you mean `"/" to "/-"` ?    Does the dash only occur after `blog/` ?

Comment: Actually its "/-" to "/" Yes this will appear only after "blog/"

Comment: Sorry, after the slash you want to remove the dash, is that correct? **EXAMPLE** `blog/-articlename` will become `blog/articlename`

Comment: Correct. And I want to ask - will this be a heavy function for the server, will it slow down the website? Any negatives?

Comment: Can you clarify a little more about WHY you need to do this. Is it because there is already another menu item with the name without the slash? If so - rewriting the request to remove the hyphen will only cause you to hit the clash you were trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/-(.*)   /blog/$1   [L]
```

Comment: This look great but maybe I'm doing something wrong couse it doesn't work. I'll edit my post and add the htacces I'm using to show you on which places I've tried to paste this rule.